# How to set a custom path to PersistantStore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'like to Core Data in app and today extension. But, my entity is always empty. I guess there is some problem about url.

So, I check my directory. And then I can check my document status is closed. File is existed. but, I can't really open. how do I open it?

here is core data method in custom core dat class:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:
        self.managedObjectModel)
    let directory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group....")

    let url = directory!.appendingPathComponent("name.sqlite")

    let document = UIManagedDocument(fileURL: url)

    if document.documentState == .normal {
        NSLog("document is normal status")
    }

    if document.documentState == .closed {

        let fileExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)
        NSLog("fileExist =\(fileExist)")

        document.open(completionHandler: { (success: Bool) in
            if success {
                NSLog("document is opened!")
            }else {
                NSLog("document is still clodsed!")
                return
            }
        })

        NSLog("document is closed")
    }


    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType:
            NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                           configurationName: nil,
                                           at: url,
                                           options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSLog("CoreData error \(error), \(error._userInfo)")
        self.errorHandler(error)
    }
    return coordinator
}()
```

here is the log:

```
fileExist =true
document is closed
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIManagedDocument can only read documents that are file packages'
```

is it correct access??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `UIManagedDocument`:

```
let baseUrl = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group....")

var storeUrl = baseUrl.appendingPathComponent(momdName)
storeUrl = storeUrl.appendingPathExtension("sqlite")

...

try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeUrl, options: nil)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
if let docsDir = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let url = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("MyDocumentName")
            let document = UIManagedDocument(fileURL: url)

            if document.documentState == .normal {

            } else if document.documentState == .closed {
                if fm.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
                    document.open(completionHandler: { (success) in

                    })
                } else {
                    document.save(to: document.fileURL, for: .forCreating, completionHandler: { (success) in

                    })
                }
            }
        }
```